# Android read & parse HttpUrlConnection response

Tags: android, response, httpurlconnection

I have a little issue with my code which I am using to read the response from web server.I get the whole information as a data packets so I have to parse the whole response and get the whole packets which server is sending to me. I don't have problem with the JSON data, but when server sends me a binary data my application crash because I can't get the whole binary data in 30KB (I'm reading the response in pieces of 30KB). So can anyone just help me a little bit which is the best way to get the response in pieces and parse it?
Here is the sample code which I'm using :

```
    public void handleDataFromSync(String responseBody) {

        RPCPacket packet;
        X:for(int index=0;index<responseBody.length();index++){
            try {
                    Log.w("Response ","Response size : "+ responseBody.length());
                    Log.w("Response ","Response : "+ responseBody);
                    Log.w("","****************Index is : "+index);
                    Log.i("","BufferString FIRST CHECK OF BUFFER : "+bufferString);

                if(bufferString!=null){

                    shitavaRabota = bufferString.concat(responseBody);
                    Log.v("","ShitavaRabota : "+shitavaRabota);
                    //
                    bufferString = shitavaRabota;
                        Log.i("","BufferString = SHITAVA RABOTA : "+bufferString);
                        Log.i("","BufferString SUBSTR : "+bufferString.substring(0));
                        Log.v("","BufferString LNHTG : "+bufferString.length());
                    remainingSize+=responseBody.length();
                        Log.i("","remeinign size : "+remainingSize);
                        Log.i("","neededSize size : "+neededSize);
                    if(neededSize<remainingSize){
                        data=null;
                        data = bufferString.substring(0, getLastPacketRemainingSize+getSize);
                            Log.v("","DataSize : "+dataSize);
                            Log.w("Response ","Data (CHAR, any length, in BASE64) : "+ data);
                            Log.i("","bufferString current value : "+bufferString.substring(index, index + dataSize));

                        index = (index + dataSize)-1;
                            Log.w("","****************Index is must be  : "+index);
                            Log.e("","Data Size : "+data.length());
                        first = Base64.decode(data);
                        String string = new String(first, "UTF-8");
                            Log.w("Response ","BASE 64 : "+ string);

                        packet = new RPCPacket( objectIdentificator,
                                                        RPCPacketType.getPacketTypeByValue(pType),
                                                        RPCOperationType.getByValue(operationType),
                                                        objectOId,
                                                        id,
                                                        dataSize,
                                                        hashH,
                                                        RPCPacketDataType.getByValue(dataType),
                                                        first);

                        parseRPCPacket(packet);

                        int bLength = bufferString.length()-dataSize;
                        responseBody = bufferString.substring(bLength);
                            Log.e("","ResponseBody = BufferString : "+responseBody);
                        shitavaRabota = null;
                    } else if(neededSize>remainingSize) {
                        bufferString = bufferString.concat(responseBody.substring(index, responseBody.length()-index));
                            Log.i("","BufferString : "+bufferString);

                    }
                }


                Log.v("","index before objectId : "+index);
                Log.v("","index before objectId 2 : "+(index+packetFieldSizes[0]));
                objectIdentificator = 0;
                objectIdentificator = Integer.parseInt(responseBody.substring(index,index+packetFieldSizes[0]));
                    Log.w("Response ","Object Identificator (LONGINT) : "+ objectIdentificator);
                    Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index,index+packetFieldSizes[0]));

                index = index+packetFieldSizes[0];
                    Log.w("","****************Index is  : "+index);


                pType = Short.parseShort(responseBody.substring(index,index + packetFieldSizes[1]));
                    Log.w("Response ","TYPE (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ pType);
                    Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index,index + packetFieldSizes[1]));

                index = index + packetFieldSizes[1];
                    Log.w("","****************Index is  : "+index);



                operationType = Short.parseShort(responseBody.substring(index,index + packetFieldSizes[2]));
                    Log.w("Response ","OPERATION (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ operationType);
                    Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index,index + packetFieldSizes[2]));

                index = index + packetFieldSizes[2];
                    Log.w("","****************Index is  : "+index);


                objectOId=null;
                objectOId = responseBody.substring(index, index + packetFieldSizes[3]);
                    Log.w("Response ","UID (CHAR, length 32) : "+ objectOId);
                    Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index, index + packetFieldSizes[3]));

                index = index + packetFieldSizes[3];
                    Log.w("","****************Index is : "+index);


                id=0;
                id = Integer.parseInt(responseBody.substring(index,index + packetFieldSizes[4]));
                    Log.w("Response ","ID (LONGINT) : "+ id);
                    Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index, index + packetFieldSizes[4]));

                index = index + packetFieldSizes[4];
                    Log.w("","****************Index is (must be 102) : "+index);

                dataSize = 0;
                dataSize = Integer.parseInt(responseBody.substring(index,index + packetFieldSizes[5]));
                    Log.w("Response ","Data Size (LONGINT) : "+ dataSize);
                    Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index, index + packetFieldSizes[5]));


                index = index + packetFieldSizes[5];
                    Log.w("","****************Index is (must be 134) : "+index);


                hashH=null;
                hashH = responseBody.substring(index,index + packetFieldSizes[6]);
                    Log.w("Response ","Data Hash (CHAR, length 32 : "+ hashH);
                    Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index, index + packetFieldSizes[6]));


                index = index + packetFieldSizes[6];
                    Log.w("","****************Index is (must be 166) : "+index);

                dataType= 0;
                dataType = Short.parseShort(responseBody.substring(index,index + packetFieldSizes[7]));
                    Log.w("Response ","Data Type (UNSIGNED BYTE) : "+ dataType);
                    Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index, index + packetFieldSizes[7]));

                index = index + packetFieldSizes[7];
                    Log.w("","****************Index is (must be 169) : "+index);


                neededSize = dataSize; // cherna magiq
                remainingSize = (responseBody.length()-index);
                    Log.v("","NeededSize : "+neededSize);
                    Log.v("","Response length "+remainingSize);


               getSize = neededSize - remainingSize;
               Log.v("","getSize : "+getSize);

                if(neededSize<remainingSize){
                    data=null;
                    data = responseBody.substring(index, index + dataSize);
                        Log.w("Response ","Data (CHAR, any length, in BASE64) : "+ data);
                        Log.i("","Response current value : "+responseBody.substring(index, index + dataSize));

                    index = (index + dataSize)-1;
                        Log.w("","****************Index is must be  : "+index);
                    first = Base64.decode(data);
                    String string = new String(first, "UTF-8");
                        Log.w("Response ","BASE 64 : "+ string);

                    packet = new RPCPacket( objectIdentificator,
                                                    RPCPacketType.getPacketTypeByValue(pType),
                                                    RPCOperationType.getByValue(operationType),
                                                    objectOId,
                                                    id,
                                                    dataSize,
                                                    hashH,
                                                    RPCPacketDataType.getByValue(dataType),
                                                    first);

                    parseRPCPacket(packet);
                } else if(neededSize>remainingSize){
                        Log.i("","Sorry you don't have enough space, take the second part of stream.");
                        getLastPacketRemainingSize = remainingSize;
                        if(bufferString==null){
                            bufferString = responseBody.substring(index, remainingSize);
                            Log.i("","BufferString IF : "+bufferString);
                        } else if(bufferString!=null){
                            bufferString = bufferString.concat(responseBody.substring(index, remainingSize));
                            Log.i("","BufferString ELSE : "+bufferString);
                        }
                            break X;
                }
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }/* catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}
}
```

Comment: It's throwing a NumberFormatException because this code is not concating rightthe two pieces of response and I can't parse `objectIdentificator ` as Integer, because I'm getting string type, instead of integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet is rather hard to read. What's `RPCPacket`? What's `bufferString`? Are `Log` lines really essential to understand the logic?

Do you really have to repeat the main loop once per every character of `responseBody`, which is what you're doing now?

Also, the whole notion of having response as `String` kinda smells unfriendly to binary data.

EDIT: to get the first 32 bytes from a byte array, use:

```
byte []Source;
byte []First = Arrays.copyOf(Source, 32);
```

And please don't treat binary data as String. Corruption will be almost inevitable.

Comment: RPCPacket is a class which I'm using to define the packets.It's like base class.And I'm using `String`, because I can get the first 32 symbols, which are the ID of packet, the next 3 are are indicating the dataType and etc.I don't know how to get the first 32 symbols from `byte[]` in Java and I don't think that I can do that, that's why I'm using String. About bufferString, it's a `String` where I save the piece of response if it's too big and it's not enough to create a whole packet and wait for the next piece of response, concat them and trying to parse.Actually there is my problem...